# Append item to every list in list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to append item to every list in a list of list.

I had expected the following code to work:

```
start_list = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]

end_list = [item.append("test") for item in start_list]
```

with expected output `[["a", "b", "test"], ["c", "d", "test"]]`

instead i get `[None, None]`

First, why does this occur, and second, how do i achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) modifies the list and returns None.

If you want to generate a new list:

```
end_list = [item + ["test"] for item in start_list]
```

If you want to modify the old list:

```
for sublist in start_list:
    sublist.append("test")
```